# Laravel Simple Nested Select Statement with Relationship

Tags: laravel, select, nested, eloquent, relationship

I have a mySql query that I need to convert using Eloquent(**recommended**) if possible.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM  
( SELECT `uid`, `revision` FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `revision` DESC)  
x GROUP by uid
```

In my `Project` model I have the following:

```
$this->hasMany('\App\Task', 'project_id');
```

And now, How do I convert the **sql query** above using **eloquent**.
Any help is appreciated.

Cheers all.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018466/laravel-proper-way-to-get-eloquent-to-create-nested-select

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is `DB::select` in laravel which is essential in this case.

Here is the solution:

```
$sub = 'SELECT * FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `revision` DESC';
                $results = DB::select(
                        DB::raw('select * from (' . $sub . ') x GROUP by uid')
                );
```